# Sequence in span with disjoints supports has (?) block subsequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Assume $b_k \in <e_i, \text{with coefficients} \  a_i^k \geq 0>$ is a sequence and $a_i^k$ have disjoint supports(support is the set where $a_i^k \neq 0$). Is there a way to prove or disprove that i can find a subsequence of $b_k$ that is block sequence of $e_i?$

Answer (score 0):

I think i solved it. One kane take $k_1 = 1$ and say $g_1=\sum_{r=1}^m a_r^k f_r.$ Then there are only finite $g_k$'s with coefficients that iclude at least one $a_r \leq a_m^k.$ Thus there exists $g_{k_2}$ with $g_{k_2}=\sum_{r=n}^N a_r^{k+1} f_r,$ where $n > m.$ We continue like that.